# GTM tracking using React Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, google-tag-manager, react-context

I want to implement **page tracking** using a combination of [React Context](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and "deferred calls" of function that sends the collected data.

The **idea** is:

1. Create Provider of this Context and place it on the top level of the React tree.
2. Save the **common data** used on each page to this Context. For example, it can be a language, user status, any account data, etc.
3. Make the functionality that **sends the common data automatically** on **all pages** on location change **except those that uses the hook that uses this Context**. This hook (or HOC) is intended to extend the common data with what can be obtained on the page. And the sending will be done **not automatically**, but using **callback** when all data for extention will be loaded.

**Question:**

How to prevent automatic data sending if a page uses the Context in which the data extension is supposed to be sent?

**A quick example**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { location } from 'react-router-dom';

const Context = React.createContext({
  trackPage: () => {}
});

function Provider({ children, initialDataLayer = {} }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [dataLayer, setDataLayer] = React.useState(initialDataLayer);

  // in the original it is used not to send data twice
  const isTrackedOnce = React.useRef(false);

  const trackPage = React.useCallback((data) => {
    (window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []).push({ ...dataLayer, ...data });
  }, [dataLayer]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //  how to prevent automatic tracking
    // if I am going to do it manually using the Сontext on some page?
    trackPage();
  }, [trackPage, location.pathname]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ trackPage }}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
}

// hook
function usePageTracking() {
  return React.useContext(Context);
}

// some page
function Page() {
  // ❗️ the page uses Сontext.
  // React.useEffect from the Provider should not track page automatically
  // if `trackPage` callback from the Context is expected to be called manually 
  const { trackPage } = usePageTracking();

  return <div>content</div>;
}
```

**PS:** any other ideas?

Comment: You can store the valid location where trackPage function will run automatically, example: const paths=["path1", ...], then check the pathname before calling trackPage();

Comment: Yup, but this method is used now with a slightly different implementation and I would like to avoid it 